# Phaser P2 Physics Hollow sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

I am making a game with Phaser using P2 physics and I want to make a "Hollow" sprite. What I mean is I want a sprite in the shape of a square/rectangle that the player can be inside, so it cant be a solid body. I would also like to make one with a hole in it so the player can move inside. Currently the ways that I can think of of making it are a custom polygon or multiple sprites, Are there simpler ways? and, If I make a custom polygon that has no hole can I avoid a line going through it at the end of the polygon?

Comment: did you ever solve this?